# Office 365 throws strange error when calling EWS findFolders on ARCHIVE ROOT

Tags: office365, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

Last 3 days we see (starting on February 1st 2020) we see on many customers error when trying to find folders under ARCHIVE ROOT using EWS findFolders : "The requesting account does not have permission to serialize tokens". Before February 1st, everything was fine, there was few here and there, but now it's happen a lot.

Please advise what is this and how it can be fixed ?

Update - request / response log

```
POST /EWS/Exchange.asmx HTTP/1.1
X-AnchorMailbox: xxxxx@aaaa.com
Content-Length: 1106
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Host: outlook.office365.com
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.9 (Java/1.8.0_60)
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Authorization: Basic 

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">
    <soap:Header>
        <t:RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2016"/>
        <t:ExchangeImpersonation>
            <t:ConnectingSID>
                <t:PrincipalName>xxxxx@aaaa.com</t:PrincipalName>
            </t:ConnectingSID>
        </t:ExchangeImpersonation>
    </soap:Header>
    <soap:Body>
        <FindFolder xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages" xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" Traversal="Deep">
            <FolderShape>
                <t:BaseShape>AllProperties</t:BaseShape>
                <t:AdditionalProperties>
                    <t:FieldURI FieldURI="folder:ParentFolderId"/>
                    <t:FieldURI FieldURI="folder:DisplayName"/>
                    <t:FieldURI FieldURI="folder:FolderClass"/>
                    <t:FieldURI FieldURI="folder:DistinguishedFolderId"/>
                </t:AdditionalProperties>
            </FolderShape>
            <IndexedPageFolderView MaxEntriesReturned="500" Offset="0" BasePoint="Beginning"/>
            <ParentFolderIds>
                <t:DistinguishedFolderId Id="archiveroot"/>
            </ParentFolderIds>
        </FindFolder>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>


HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Cache-Control: private
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
request-id: f7ddc493-4389-4856-8d35-f8ddf435dd71
X-CalculatedFETarget: BN6PR10CU002.internal.outlook.com
X-BackEndHttpStatus: 500
Set-Cookie: exchangecookie=a2abababacecb6dc6d05fb2a8f30e7; expires=Thu, 04-Feb-2021 09:03:08 GMT; path=/; secure; HttpOnly
X-FEProxyInfo: BN6PR10CA0047.NAMPRD10.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM
X-CalculatedBETarget: BN7PR13MB2388.namprd13.prod.outlook.com
X-BackEndHttpStatus: 500
X-RUM-Validated: 1
X-MailboxGuid: 1c882ca8-aaaa-4444-8888-abcd410c5b0
x-EwsHandler: FindFolder
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-BeSku: WCS5
X-DiagInfo: BN7PR13MB2388
X-BEServer: BN7PR13MB2388
X-Proxy-RoutingCorrectness: 1
X-Proxy-BackendServerStatus: 500
X-FEServer: BN6PR10CA0047
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
X-FEServer: MN2PR05CA0041
Date: Tue, 04 Feb 2020 09:03:07 GMT

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <s:Body>
        <s:Fault>
            <faultcode xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">a:ErrorTokenSerializationDenied</faultcode>
            <faultstring xml:lang="en-US">The requesting account does not have permission to serialize tokens.</faultstring>
            <detail>
                <e:ResponseCode xmlns:e="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/errors">ErrorTokenSerializationDenied</e:ResponseCode>
                <e:Message xmlns:e="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/errors">The requesting account does not have permission to serialize tokens.</e:Message>
            </detail>
        </s:Fault>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Thanks